# unable to submit form on first click in jquery with validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, form-submit

I am developing a simple login form with validation and everything is working  fine but itrs not triggering on first click,here is my code JS file:

```
$("form#login-form").submit(function(e){

e.preventDefault();    

//Form Validation goes here....

//Save Form Data........
$('form#login-form').validate({ // initialize the plugin
    rules: {
        userName: "required",
        password: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5
        },
        agree: "required"
    },

    // Specify the validation error messages
    messages: {
        userName: "Please enter a user name",
        password: {
            required: "Please provide a password",
            minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
        },
        email: "Please enter a valid email address",
        agree: "Please accept our policy"
    },

    submitHandler: function (form) {
        $('#spinner').css('visibility', 'visible');
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            url : 'api/Values/GetName',
            type: "POST",
            dataType : "json",
            data : data,
            context : Form,
            success: function (callback) {
                $.each(callback, function (key, val) {
                    if (val === 'True') {
                        window.location.href = "Templates/internetSales.html";
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#fail').css('visibility', 'visible');
                    }

                });


                $('#spinner').css('visibility', 'hidden');
            },
            error : function(){
                $(this).html("Server Error!");
            }
        });
    }

});

      }                   );
```

html code goes here:

```
<form id="login-form" novalidate="novalidate">
        <input type="text" name="userName" id="userName" placeholder="UserName" />
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
        <input type="submit" id="loginSubmit"value="Log in" />
        <p id="fail" class="fail">Login failed try again!</p>
    </form>
```

I dont know in debugger it goes to debug point to validate function on first click but nothing happens,i have tried multiple approaches but does'nt help.Please provide where i am getting wrong.

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fxv95/)

Comment: Please explain problem using this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Fxv95/

Comment: @Pratik Joshi yeah in this fiddle only you can observe that it gets validated on second click

Comment: Is this only in a certain browser?  Try adding an `action=` to your form tag or an onsubmit return false.

Comment: Please check working fiddle in answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bingo , You dont need to have

```
$("form#login-form").submit(function(e){        
e.preventDefault();
});
```

Working fiddle [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fxv95/1/)

Comment: You may do +1 if it solved your problem.

Comment: just one more thing in this inseide submit handler how can i get form values as var form =this,here this is not referencing to current form

Comment: u mean u want to get Textboxes values within submithandler?

Comment: yeah in json format as i was getting u can see in my commented code posted above as
   var data = [];
                var Form = $(form[name = "login-form"]);

                ////Gathering the Data
                ////and removing undefined keys(buttons)
                $.each(this.elements, function (i, v) {
                    var input = $(v);
                    data[input.attr("name")] = input.val();
                    delete data["undefined"];
                });

Comment: Then check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Fxv95/3/  U need to separate code for Validation and what shuld happen on click of submit